# Calculate array of unique stems in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

In javascript, I have an array of strings.

```
[
   "test",
   "tests",
   "abc",
   "abcdef"
]
```

I want to create a new array that contains only the unique stems of the strings.  For example, the above array would reduce to...

```
[
   "test",
   "abc"
]
```

...because "test" is a stem of "tests" and "abc" is a stem of "abcdef".

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I was not the downvoter, I dont know the reason, but have you looked at any stemming algorithms in js/jquery ?

Comment: What would you expect as result from `["testa","testb","tesa","tea","ta","t"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also use underscore string. [https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string]

```
// make a new array that is the old array without...
var myArrayWithNoStems =_.without(myArray,function(word) {
  // anything that matches the filter
   return _.find(myArray, function(word2) {
      // if this word wholly includes another word, return true
      if (word != word2 && _.str.include(word, word2)) return true;
    })
});
```

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis just before `return true;`, and also the closing parenthesis for the call to `_.find`.

Comment: I couldn't do it, SO didn't count it as enough changes to be a legal edit :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to loop. First, I suggest ordering words by letter count, so you would do something like this:

```
var myArray = ["test", "tests", "abc", "abcdef"];

//this sorts from smallest to largest
myArray.sort(function(a,b){return a.length - b.length});
```

so, now myArray is sorted from smallest to largest. Now you would loop for each element to check if it is a stem of the next elements.

```
//this is the array where we will store the stems
var stemArray = [];

//the temporary stem goes here
var stem;

//this variable is used to capture a substring from each string
// to check against the stem variable
var check;

//loop over all the variables except the last
//since they are ordered from smallest to last, we are guaranteed that  
//the last object wont be much of a stem 
//and thus we can avoid that check
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++){

    //set the current stem
    stem = myArray[i];

    //then loop over the remainding objects
    for (var j = i+1; j < myArray.length; j++){

        //capture a substring
        //so for example, stem = "abc" and the element we're testing against
        //is "test", check will be equal to "tes" so the size matches "abc"
        check = myArray[j].substring(0,stem.length);

        //if stem and check are the same
        //and since you wanted unique we check if it is unique
        //alternatively, we could just break inside the next 
        //conditional statement and it would be more efficient 
        //and thus remove the indexOf test
        //but i include it to explain the logic of how the algorithm works
        if (stem === check){

            if (stemArray.indexOf(stem) === -1){
                //add the verified stem to the array of stems
                stemArray.push(stem);
            }

            //In the case of ["t", "te", "test"], the above code
            //will output ["t", "te"]
            //if you want it to output just ["t"], uncomment the following

            //myArray.splice(j,1);
            //j--;
            //these lines will remove the duplicate from myArray
            //and correct the iteration due to the deletion

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a fix for the case where you want to get ["a"] from ["a", "any", "anywhere"]

Answer (score 0):

"Simple" is relative of course.

Taking a simplistic view that the stem will always match the first characters of the longer word, sort the array so that stems come before the longer word (e.g. "test" before "tests"), then iterate over the array and test each member against following members, removing those that are an extension of a stem, e.g.

```
function getStems(arr) {
  var a = arr.slice().sort();
  var stem, len;

  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length - 1; i<iLen; i++) {
    stem = a[i];
    len = stem.length;

    while (i<iLen && stem == a[i+1].substring(0,len)) {
      a.splice(i+1, 1);
      --iLen;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

var a = ["test","tests","abcdef","abcf","abcdefqw","abc"];

alert(getStems(a)); // abc, test
```

However, given "a","any","anyone", the above will return "a", which may not be what you want.

Comment: According to his comments on the question it actually is what he'd want :)